# How to show the permissions in numeric format?

Tags: files, ls

I know that with "ls -l" I can see the permissions of a file or directory but it shows them with letters, so how to show the permissions in numeric way

for example:

755 /var/www/mywebpage

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -printf "%m %f\n"
```

or [`stat`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stat):

```
stat -c "%a %n" -- *
```

Comment: actually just `stat` works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Like stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1796009) answer on stackoverflow,

```
ls -l | awk '{k=0;for(i=0;i<=8;i++)k+=((substr($1,i+2,1)~/[rwx]/) \
         *2^(8-i));if(k)printf("%0o ",k);print}'
```

is doing exactly what you want.

Comment: It doesn't handle setuid and setgid files correctly.

Comment: Love this one-line solution answer. Exactly what I needed!